# mouseover and mousenter in loop

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tiptip

We are using jquery tiptip plugin for showing tooltips, the page is a dynamic one.

The code works fine for ie8 and firefox, but in ie7, it is getting in infinite loop and I am getting out of memory error alert. The code is,

```
    $('a[toolTip]').live('mouseover', function(e) {
        $(this).tipTip({attribute:"toolTip"});          
        $(this).trigger('mouseenter'); 

    });
```

We are using toolTip as the attribute to tiptip. When I remove the trigger mouseenter line of code, it is working in IE7 too, but not on the first hover, only on the second hover. That's why I have added the below line of code

```
$(this).trigger('mouseenter');
```

Please help me to fix this infinite looping in IE7.

Regards
Hari

Comment: Only on the 2nd hover eh? I'm willing to bet that you have an ajax call that invokes this mouseover function. That's the only plausible scenario. Also, we don't use .live() anymore. we use `.delegate()` or `.on()`, such as `$(document).on('mouseover', 'a[toolTip]', function(e){ // stuff });` [Here's a working jsFiddle utilizing your same methods.](http://jsfiddle.net/kZYzP/)

Comment: Yes, it is working only on second hover. If I use, on instead of live, the result is same, $(document).on('hover', 'a[toolTip]', function(e){ $(this).tipTip({attribute:"toolTip"}); });.This will not work on first hover. If I add $(document).on('hover', 'a[toolTip]', function(e){ $(this).tipTip({attribute:"toolTip"});$(this).trigger('mouseenter');   });, it is causing out of memory in IE7 due to infinite looping

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem, the tooltip is shown after the 2nd hover :(

Answer (score 1):

Tool tip works on the second hover because the at the first hover the attribute is not set. The infinite loop occurs because you are again triggering the mouse event on the handler which should not be done. While going through the site of tiptip plugin, the way to initialize the plugin is :

```
 $("a[toolTip]").tipTip({"attribute":"tooltip"});
```

This will in turn call automatically when you hover on the element. No need to separately attach mouse events for the elements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it will not work for dynamic content using ajax. There will be no anchor tags on start up, the contents are loaded using an ajax call, so this will not work

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at the documentation. Seems that the easiest way to achieve this is.

`$('a[toolTip]').tipTip({'activation' : 'hover'});`

This will ensure all elements are activated by the hover function, and you don't have to worry about delegating event handlers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it will not work for dynamic content using ajax. There will be no anchor tags on start up, the contents are loaded using an ajax call, so this will not work